# Is timing important during combat?

Tags: legend-of-grimrock

When fighting monsters does it matter the moment when you press attack? Or should I just press attack buttons as fast as possible in order to maximize the damage output?

[image: flying monster]

Comment: Fighter, Fighter, Mage, Rogue... deja vu! The only difference is that my minotaur specializes in maces, and my rogue in ranged weapons. :-)

Comment: I just chose the classical approach for a soft start :) It has passed long time since my last play to Eye of the Beholder.

Comment: LoG specifically encourages this party mix; the ratio of gear in the dungeon (which is fixed, not random) is pretty specific to one heavy armor user, one light, one evasion, and one mage.

Comment: @MyrddinEmrys The default party consists of two fighters, a rogue, and a wizard. It's safe to assume that the gear found throughout the game is tailored for that setup. There is no specific way you're supposed to gear your characters though, and I don't see why you'd put light armor on a fighter when you can put a couple more points into the armor skill tree and wear heavy armor instead. Whether your rogue uses light armor or goes unarmored is up to you, and the same thing goes for whether you want your wizard to wear protection or evasion gear.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As long as you swing at a time when the monster is in the square in front of you (by the way, you can hit ogres as they charge past!) then the timing does not change your chance to hit or do damage. I swing all my easy weapons first, then click the spell glyphs while all my other characters are on cooldown, to reduce wasted time.

However, it is smart to stagger your swings, as it is possible to significantly reduce your damage received if the monster stays staggered often. I aim to swing about once a second to maximize their stunned time, even though it slightly reduces my damage per second.

Comment: I tried the "stagger them" approach, but usually I found it easier to unload all attacks at once, then just strafe away while I waited for a reset. I was playing on Hard, though, which may have made a difference... on that difficulty, staggering them or not, standing still and while they beat the crap out of your front line resulted in quick deaths.

Comment: I'll have to do some testing, but I really got the impression that skeletons would stagger more easily if I damaged them after they started their attack animation, rather than just attacking them whenever.

Comment: @Tacroy I had the same feeling against skeletons but not against flying monsters, like the one in picture. Maybe is just a feeling or maybe it is better following different approaches against different mobs.

Comment: @tacroy No, I agree, you can definitely stagger monsters. My point was that (at least least on the difficulty I played) standing still and trying to mitigate damage via staggering them was far less effective than simply unloading all my attacks immediately and then strafing out of their way until I was reset. I think you definitely raised an interesting issue on how you could use some timing to your advantage... I just feel it's a weaker overall strategy than getting out of the way.

Answer (score 5):

Timing doesn't matter in terms of the amount of damage a hit does, though it may matter in terms of actually landing a hit. Obviously if you swing at a monster before it moves into a square next to you, you'll hit nothing but air. But assuming your attack will hit, you should generally attack as early and as often as possible!

Position, however, CAN matter. Some attacks, such as a rogue's backstab ability, trigger if you are able to get a rear attack on the monster. So sometimes it can pay off to spend a few extra seconds maneuvering for a better position on a slow creature (particularly ogres).

Answer (score 0):

I haven't seen any difference, just swing away! :D